# How to remove apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png errors from apache log and keep iOS icon effects

Tags: html, ios, apache, icons

The title about sums it up.

I want to get rid of all those 404 errors in the log for apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png without having to add such an image, thus losing the iOS icon effects.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `mod_rewrite` to force an error that doesn't go in the error log? Or a zero-length file?

Comment: @tc. Uploading a zero-length file does seem to work, as long as I do this for all sizes. This should be added as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:

- Use `mod_rewrite` to force an error, using the flags `[F]` (403 forbidden), `[G]` (410 gone), or `[R=404,L]` (a "redirect" to a 404). I think these skip the error log.
- Use a zero-length file (if the device supports this).

Comment: Thanks again. I went with the zero-length option which seem to work well.